# git config mergetools - tfvc syntax documentation

Tags: git, git-config, tfvc, mergetool

My .gitconfig (I got this code from [github](https://gist.github.com/DamianReeves/35adf89992f8d871afe6) and there the following questions are not documented/answered):

```
[merge]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = 'E:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/vsdiffmerge.exe' $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED //m
    keepbackup = false
    trustexistcode = true

[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = 'E:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/vsdiffmerge.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE //t
    keepbackup = false
    trustexistcode = true
```

1) What does `//t` mean? I cannot find a documentation about that.

2) //m is "documented" [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/de-de/docs/tfvc/compare-files). I would be also interested what the purpose `//m` is. Why do I need do specify `//m` when I already have specified four parameters? That does not make any syntactical sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in the meantime:

> Use the /t switch to open the comparison in a “ProvisionalTab”

Comment: I have another question. Is it possible to open the mergetool in a new vs instance? I think it's not worth to open a new thread.

Comment: Would you really want that? VS doesn't exactly boot fast.